# Debugging sorting algorithm in C (QuickSort variation)

Tags: c, sorting, debugging, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

Part of the task was to sort the columns of each section of a three-dimensional array of size P, M, N by the sum of their elements. To do this, I need to modify the given algorithm, which is a variation of QuickSort on C.

```
void QuickSort(int L, int R)
{
    int B, tmp, i, j;
    B = VectA[(L + R) / 2];
    i = L;
    j = R;
    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (VectA[i] < B)
            i = i + 1;
        while (VectA[j] > B)
            j = j - 1;
        if (i <= j)
        {
            tmp = VectA[i];
            VectA[i] = VectA[j];
            VectA[j] = tmp;
            i = i + 1;
            j = j - 1;
        }
    }
    if (L < j)
        QuickSort(L, j);
    if (i < R)
        QuickSort(i, R);
}
```

I tried to solve it like this:

```
void QuickSort_3D(int L, int R, int currP)
{
    printf("%d %d %d\n", L, R, currP);
    int B, tmp, i, j;
    int *Sum = (int *)malloc((R - L) * sizeof(int)); 
    for (int i = 0; i < R; i++)
    {
        Sum[i - L] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            Sum[i] += Arr3D[currP][j][i];
        }
    }
    B = Sum[(R - (R-L)/2) - L];
    printf("B = %d %d\n", B,(R - (R-L)/2) - L);
    i = L;
    j = R;
    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (Sum[i - L] < B)
            i = i + 1;
        while (Sum[j - L] > B)
            j = j - 1;
        if (i <= j)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < M; k++)
            { 
                tmp = Arr3D[currP][k][i];
                Arr3D[currP][k][i] = Arr3D[currP][k][j];
                Arr3D[currP][k][j] = tmp;
            }
            tmp = Sum[i - L];
            Sum[i - L] = Sum[j - L];
            Sum[j - L] = tmp;
            i = i + 1;
            j = j - 1;
        }
    }
    printf("FREE\n");
    free(Sum);
    printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
    if (L < j)
    {
        QuickSort_3D(L, j, currP);
    }
    if (i < R)
    {
        QuickSort_3D(i, R, currP);
    }
    printf("back\n");
}
```

Call of this function:

```
for (int p = 0; p < P; p++)
{
    Sort(0, N, p);
}
```

But it always falls with `Process returned -1073740940 (0xC0000374)` error when it tries to free the memory of the Sum array with `free(Sum);` after a couple of calls, and the last thing that appears in the console is the message `FREE`. Also, if I use debug mode, it stops exactly on that line where it tries to free Sum array.

I would be grateful for any help or suggestions you could provide. As a beginner in programming, any feedback or corrections to my work would be greatly appreciated and very helpful.

Comment: Have you run with a debugger? That can probably tell you where it's crashing. Additionally, using the `-fsanitize=address` flag during compilation, and running with Valgrind can both help diagnose memory errors.

Comment: One problem at least is here: `while (Sum[j - L] > B)`. `j=R`, so the first iteration of that loop, `j==R` and `L==0`, so `Sum[j-L]` is really `Sum[R]`, which is out of bounds, you can only access `Sum` up to `R-1`.

Comment: furthermore, it would be much easier to help if you created a [mre] instead of this hodgepodge of functions. What is `Sort` for instance, `QuickSort_3D`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing to negative indices of `Sum`, which is messing up the allocation information there.

Just about everything is wrong with your use of `L` and `R` for the `Sum` array. First off, you allocated `R - L` elements, when it should be `R - L + 1`. `L` through `R` is *inclusive*.

Second, your loop is `for (int i = 0; i < R; i++)`, which is the wrong number of times. The loop needs to execute `R - L + 1` times, not `R` times. It needs to be `for (int i = L; i <= R; i++)` or `for (int i = 0; i <= R - L; i++)`.

Third, your initialization `Sum[i - L] = 0;` is the negative indexing that's messing with `free()`. If your `for` loop starts at zero, that should be `Sum[i + L] = 0;`. Or if it starts at `L`, then just `Sum[i] = 0;`.

Fourth, the summing index doesn't even agree with the initialization index! You have `Sum[i] +=` ..., when the initialization was `Sum[i - L]`. At least the initialization and summing should agree.

I stopped looking at this point. There are more errors.

In any case, these sums should absolutely *not* be repeated for every quick sort call. Do the sums *once* for all of the data, before calling quick sort. Then have quick sort use the already calculated sums to determine the ordering of elements.